# Browser cache images served from Dropbox

Tags: javascript, caching, dropbox

I'm writing an application that uses Dropbox as the source of image files which are loaded via javascript by assigning img.src = "[Dropbox download link]". This works fine, but I'm often fetching many files at a time, and when re-loading a set of images (say, on a page reload), the browser re-sends a request for each one (which returns 304 not modified). I'd like to have the browser cache the image on the initial load so I can simply avoid the re-requests altogether, but can't figure out how to enable browser caching of these images. Can I set cache headers in this situation? The response headers from Dropbox have "cache-control" set to "no-cache".

Comment: Unless you've got access to dropbox's servers I'd say your out of luck :) You could stick a layer inbetween dropbox and your web server that does the caching for you. But I'd be closely looking at dropbox's terms of service because something tells me they will not be crazy about this :)

Comment: You're using Dropbox for which it was not invented! Try using [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com) instead. They have free plan also.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use HTML5's [application cache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/). But I'm pretty sure you wont be able to serve the manifest file from dropbox either.