# Why slider is loading images again and again?

Tags: jquery, slider

I am trying to use the slider at http://www.skitter-slider.net/
I have deployed it here: http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105046436/index.html at the GALLERY Page.

As I'm watching the Network panel in Chrome Dev Tools, it seems the **plugin loads the image each time it is displayed, not just once.** Am I right ? If yes, any way to fix this ? (or maybe add a caching option ...)

**This is not happening at the main site**(http://www.skitter-slider.net/)

Any suggestions would be helpful

My JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var box_skitter_large = null;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".box_skitter").skitter({ 
            theme: "square", 
            numbers_align: "center", 
            dots: true, 
            preview: true, 
            focus: true, 
            focus_position: "leftTop", 
            controls: true, 
            controls_position: "leftTop", 
            progressbar: true, 
            enable_navigation_keys: true, 
            onLoad: function(self) {
                if (this.thumbs) $('.border-skitter').height(350);
                box_skitter_large = self;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

My HTML Code:

```
<div class="box_skitter skitter-square" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; position: relative; z-index: 9999;">
    <ul style="display: none;">
        <li><img src="/u/105046436/images/gallery/1.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="/u/105046436/images/gallery/2.jpg" /></li>
        .
        .
        .
        <li><img src="/u/105046436/images/gallery/16.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i would say you are forcing in some way to not use cache server side, check and see your response header: `cache-control:no-cache`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think my problem is related to [Browser cache images served from Dropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979125/browser-cache-images-served-from-dropbox)

I'm using dropbox to test my files. The response headers from Dropbox probably have "cache-control" set to "no-cache".

Comment: so use your own server to display image. BTW it's nice you have posted this as answer, could help other people.

Comment: yes, thanks.
If images are loaded again and again, the slider transitions start lagging.